# merge 2/3 image into 1 image with divided by each image using drawinRect iOS objective C

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, xcode8, ios10, drawimage

I have upload multiple image (2/3), and i want to show it on my home screen at my single UIImageView with aspect ratio of 1:1 when it still uploading. So, i draw those image with this code:

```
PHCachingImageManager *imageManager = [PHCachingImageManager new];
CGSize canvasSize = CGSizeMake(100*self.uploadAssets.count, 100);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(canvasSize);

for (int i = 0; i < self.uploadAssets.count; i++){
    if ([self.uploadAssets[i] isKindOfClass:[PHAsset class]]) {
        PHAsset *asset = self.uploadAssets[i];


        [imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                                targetSize:CGSizeMake(350,350)
                               contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                   options:nil
                             resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result,
                                             NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                                 if (result) {
                                     [result drawInRect:CGRectMake(i*100, 0, 100, 100)];
                                 }
                             }];
    }else if ([self.uploadAssets[i] isKindOfClass:[Item class]]) {
        Item *item = self.uploadAssets[i];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: item.images[0]];
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(i*100, 0, 100, 100)];
    }
}

UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.uploadImage = finalImage;
```

The problem is those 3 image becomes too flat ([flat image on the top](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/219x389q90/r/922/IvknrX.png)) and not proportional.
I want those image to become [propotional like this](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/219x389q90/r/921/cAPoJD.png)

I have change my UIImageView to AspectFill or AspectFit or default, but none of those make the shown image properly. What should i change ? Can i crop my image to the middle only for each photo?

Comment: instead of assigning this image to imageView try to add it as layer content and then set the gravity to AspectFill/ AspectFit. May be it become helpful

Comment: what do you mean by add my finalImage as layer content? i don`t really understand, still new in iOS development

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning image to a `UIImageView`
Create an Empty `UIView` object with the frame size that you need as in your case may be `width = 100`and`height = 100`

And at the end at the UIImage object to that newly created view's layer like this...

```
let myLayer = CALayer()
let myImage = yourFinalImage?.cgImage
myLayer.frame = myView.bounds
myLayer.contents = myImage
myLayer.contents.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill //Change this property according to your need
myView.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)
```

Comment: got the same result exactly

Comment: try to double the image size with respect to frame.
Ex...
If your imageview width = 100 and height = 100
Then take image height and width as 200

Comment: i have tried that also, i use 200x200 if i uploaded 2 image, and 300x300 if i uploaded 3 image

Comment: ok i'll compile your code by my self and then tell you the solution.

Comment: if i use the resolution 200x200 or 300x300, my combined images will only viewed in the middle, it is nice when i upload 2 image because half of right image 1 and half of left image 2 will appear and it is not flat, the problem is when i upload 3 image. The image chich appear only image 2, because it is in the middle.